# Connection string without computer User ID-Password for SQL Server Express database in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-express

I am using Entity Framework code-first approach. Below is the connection string in my `app.config` file.

```
<add name="CommandTronContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Technical\CommandTron\CommandTron.mdf;Initial Catalog=CommandTron;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=True;"/>
```

I get an error:

> Cannot open database "CommandTron" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'username'.

But I don't want to provide user name-password for the machine. Is there a way not to provide any login details or create a new user name and password for this database only or use SQL Server Express user name password?

Comment: You're specifying `Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=True` in the connection string, which means it's using your Windows credentials for the connection, not a username + password.

Comment: do you have added your windows credential to SQL Server logins?

Comment: @ gunr2171 , thats what I thought that it should use Windows credential. But I dont why its asking for user name - password then

Comment: @ FLICKER, I am using SQL Express. So I dont know how can I set Windows credential for it

Answer (score 0):

Seems the access to the database file is faulted due to permission issue. You can set the permission in two ways:

1. Through sql server management studio (SSMS), by granting permission
   to your database.
2. or when you are trying to access the mdf directly. Try giving
   permission to the folder that contains your mdf file.

   In your case point 2 should work.

Comment: So database file doesnot exist yet. I am creating it for the first time from Entity framework code first. Can it still have faulted permissions ?

Comment: Can you please give more information how can I implement point 2?

Comment: Ohh I thought you already had an mdf file. To know the step by step process to generate a database model first approach please refer to

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205424(v=vs.113).aspx
Video link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591505(v=vs.113).aspx

I will create a database and grant the necessary permission for your application to access the DB.